# Sinatra commands do not work in modules

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app which requires a module in a different file. When I use Sinatra commands in that module (e.g. `redirect "http://facebook.com"`), I get a `NoMethodError`. To illustrate the problem, I have made a simplified version:

--- mainapp.rb ---

```
#config
require './redirector.rb'

get '/' do
   Redirector::redirect_to_stackoverflow
end
```

--- redirector.rb ---

```
module Redirector
  require 'sinatra'

  def self.redirect_to_stackoverflow
    redirect "http://stackoverflow.com"
  end
end
```

--- config.ru ---

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/ptt.rb"

run Sinatra::Application
```

What is wrong? Is there a place where I haven't required something properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `redirect` inside the `Redirector` module is sent to the `Redirector` Module object, where the method does not exist. `require 'sinatra'` inside `module Redirector` is not necessary, and does not do any kind of method composition.

You probably *could* compose Sinatra methods into your Redirector module, but that is not normal practice. Usually it's the other way around - you write "helper" modules that are composed in to your Sinatra application in various ways.

This is a similar example application, with a more usual approach to composition:

**app.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
require_relative 'redirect.rb'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Application
   include Redirector
   get '/' do
      redirect_to_stackoverflow
   end
end
```

**redirect.rb**

```
module Redirector
  def redirect_to_stackoverflow
    redirect "http://stackoverflow.com"
  end
end
```

**config.ru**

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/app.rb"
run MyApp
```

Answer (score 2):

@Neil Slater's explanation is correct, but I'd suggest you also make it an [Sinatra extension](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html#extending_the_request_context_with_), e.g.

```
require 'sinatra/base'

module Sinatra
  module Redirector
    def redirect_to_stackoverflow
      redirect "http://stackoverflow.com"
    end
  end
  helpers Redirector
end
```

Then (for a classic app) all you need to do is `require` it.

```
require 'sinatra/redirector'
get "/" do
  redirect_to_stackoverflow
end
```